# How can I skip/cancel the matching regex if something is found before the end of the pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make two regex patterns that are exclusive to each other, used in Java.

**regex one:**

match anything between `[[` and `]]` except a `|` (pipe) character or `\r\n` line break characters, catching the full match and only the text between `[[` and `]]` into groups 1 and 2 respectively:

regex: `(\[\[([^|\r\n]*?)]])`

should return 2 full matches with the following input:

```
[[wikipage&sfd/weird-]]
[[The whitespace.con_vention/+-test]]
```

**regex two:**

match everything between `[[` and `]]` except a `|` (pipe) character or `\r\n` line break characters, catching the full match and only the text before the `|` into groups 1 and 2 respectively:

regex: `(\[\[([^|\r\n]*?)\|.*?]])`

should return 2 full matches with the following input:

```
[[SandBox|the sandbox]]
[[SandBox|the.sandbox_/=test]]
```

but with the following input:

`Test [[wiki:1]], [[wiki:page]test|test ]one]], [[wiki:1|page one]]`

the First Full Match of **regex two** is:

`[[wiki:1]], [[wiki:page]test|test ]one]]`

and the Second Full Match of **regex two** is:

`[[wiki:1|page one]]`

While I expect only two full matches like this:

`[[wiki:page]test|test ]one]]`

`[[wiki:1|page one]]`

I've tried with negative lookahead like so: `(\[\[([^|\r\n]*?)(?!]])\|.*?]])` but if it finds `]]` it'll just backtrack and reuse the first part of the regex.

**So my question is:**
How do I skip/cancel the whole regex if `]]` is found before `|` ?

Comment: Where does the `ticket` comes from? Did you mix it with `wiki`? Also to clarify, 'First Full Match' is the result of the first regex, 'Second FF' the result of the second?

Comment: give the input and the expected output. thank you

Comment: Yeah, I had some of the examples mixed up, fixed now

Comment: your notation is absurdly confusing.  It's not clear at all what is the input and the output.  You say the match is "[[wiki:1]]" but nowhere in the examples above does that string even appear.  Something's off.  Please be clearer.  Input, regex, expected match, actual match.

Comment: @bertuslakkis: It's clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to allow `]]` before the first `|`, you can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this:

```
\[\[((?:(?!]])[^|\r\n])*)\|.*?]]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[\[        # Match [[
(           # Match and capture in group 1...
 (?:        # (Start of non-capturing group)
  (?!]])    # ... (unless the text "]]" is directly ahead)
  [^|\r\n]  # ... any character except pipes or newlines
 )*         # repeat as necessary (lazy evaluation is not needed here)
)           # End of capturing group
\|          # Match a pipe
.*?         # and any number of characters until
]]          # the next instance of ]]
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/iJ2cR9).

Comment: So to achieve what I wanted I had to use negative lookahead infront of `[^|\r\n]*?`, and put it in a non-capturing group. Thanks for your explanation!